# Elegant way to get machine name from URI object?

Tags: c#, uri

Say I have a URI object that looks like this:

> machine.domain.com

Is there an elegant way without manually parsing strings to get the **machine** name from URI object in C#?

Comment: No - as Uri host does not concept of "machine name" or any other way of splitting it.